# Left Join Doesn't Return Unmatched Rows As Null

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

On my Left Table I have all EMP Information joint with all possible Asset, SO all Employees are assigned to take all courses listed in the database. AND the Right Table I have Only Employees who has taken or in process of taking the course.( Both tables are queries and their results are correct)

I would like to do Left join between two tables (queries) so I get All Employees from Left-Table joint Right-Table with new columns (Completion date & Completion status)!

However, when I do left-join it returns all my rows and fills the blanks with the two possibilities for Completion Status which is Completed OR in Progress). The most stupid thing happens when I add Completion date and returns some random dates and fills all rows for Completion Dates and repeats those rows for following asset titles.

My result should be a list of all EMP joint with required courses with the status of course, this person has completed the course or not and I would like to get null for all those non related rows. Will you be kind and check my code and let me know what can cause this problem? Thank you

```
SELECT qryEmployeeCourse.[EMP ID], qryEmployeeCourse.Name, qryEmployeeCourse.Role, qryEmployeeCourse.Location, qryEmployeeCourse.Region, qryEmployeeCourse.[Asset ID], qryEmployeeCourse.[Asset Title], qryCourseStatus.[Completion Status]

FROM qryEmployeeCourse LEFT JOIN qryCourseStatus ON qryEmployeeCourse.[EMP ID] = qryCourseStatus.Username

GROUP BY qryEmployeeCourse.[EMP ID], qryEmployeeCourse.Name, qryEmployeeCourse.Role, qryEmployeeCourse.Location, qryEmployeeCourse.Region, qryEmployeeCourse.[Asset ID], qryEmployeeCourse.[Asset Title], qryCourseStatus.[Completion Status]
ORDER BY qryEmployeeCourse.Name, qryEmployeeCourse.Role, qryEmployeeCourse.Location;
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0zNVz.png here is the pic of my tables and result.

Comment: perhaps you only need to select the records with the latest `CompletionDate`

Comment: @Cha will not make any difference :( still acts like cross join

Comment: If it appears to be cross joining then you aren't joining on enough columns, or your assumptions about the cardinality of the data are incorrect. It's difficult to tell which is your issue from your screenshot and description as I can't work out what the unique constraints are on each table. Why don't you post a sample of just 'Adebule' from each source query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me that your LEFT JOIN should  be

```
qryCourseStatus ON qryEmployeeCourse.[EMP ID] = qryCourseStatus.Username AND qryEmployeeCourse.AssetID = qryCourseStatus.AssetID
```

Otherwise you will be getting a cross join (all rows in qryEmployeeCourse with all rows in qryCourseStatus, for each employee ).

In the first set of results in your screenshot, you are only getting two rows because the employees records in the qryCourseStatus only has two distinct statuses `Completed` and `In progress`, and your group by is removing all the other duplicates.

You get a lot more rows in the second set of results, because you are adding `Completion Date` which has 7 distinct values for this employee.